# Converting web logs into SQL

Tags: sql-server, windows, logging, logfiles

I have been doing a bit of research on this and cannot find a definitive answer so I figured I'd ask you guys.   I am considering writing a log file analyzer.  The log files found in the W3 (web) services, for example.   I want to be able to search these logs more quickly and compile reports if necessary.

The question is how well does SQL handle text entries?   Does it compress the text internally or is it pretty much 1-to-1?  The log files I really want to evaluate are part of a system that happens to use the standard logging format.  And the log files are quite large.   On the order of 400MB-1GB/day.   I don't necessarily plan on keeping all the information, I was just wondering how efficient this could be.

Any help here would be appreciated!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: When you say how well does SQL handle text entries, do you mean BLOB fields? This answers will vary wildly because each RDMS has it's particular way of implementing enhanced file support.

Comment: From a SQL Server approach You may want to read up on File Tables. "...you can store files and documents in special tables in SQL Server called FileTables, but access them from Windows applications as if they were stored in the file system, without making any changes to your client applications."

Comment: @RossBush I am mostly concerned with simple text.   The data in these log files contain a lot of text fields.  Part of the reason the files are so large.   I would like to push them into an SQL table for indexing and reporting.  So if I have a TEXT field and I put 250 characters into the field, does it store it as 250(ish) bytes or does it compress them somehow.  I am concerned about this growing out of control.

Comment: [See also](https://technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/dd919274), [see also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression), [see also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/create-and-manage-full-text-indexes), [see also](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana).

Comment: SQL Server supports table compression, if that's what you ask. If you want to search logs though, you need to *parse* the file, and insert it to a table with a separate column per field.

Comment: You can also use a columnstore table. This will result in dramatic space savings, as only individual *column* values will be stored. Analytic queries over a column store are orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I do plan on parsing.  Date fields for dates, Int for numbers, etc.   Thanks for the advice though.  Each record has a rather substantial textual field.

Comment: Check [From Elasticsearch back to SQL Server](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/davide_mauri/archive/2017/05/24/from-elasticsearch-back-to-sql-server.aspx). The scenario seems similar